# A group theory question relating equality of cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $x,y$ belongs to a group $G$ and $x=y$, then can i directly conclude that $xH=yH$ for any subgroup  $H$ of $G$?

Comment: Sure...it's true element by element.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, if $x=y$ then $\forall_{h\in H} \; xh = yh$. Thus, every element of $xH$ is contained in $yH$ and vice versa.
Cheers!